# How to diagnose why a VS Code using Docker Container to run does not install extensions in the container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have a Python project that I have setup to use Remote-Container to run inside a docker container.
Everything worked great, until it didn't :)

I am now facing an issue that the Docker container is created, but VS Code fails to install the required extensions in the container:

```
[52278 ms] Start: Run in container: cd /root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f; export VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server; /root/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh --disable-telemetry --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --install-extension ms-python.python --install-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance --install-extension littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter --force
[74035 ms] Installing extensions...
[74036 ms] 
[74036 ms] Exit code 1
[74037 ms] Start: Run in container: ls /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache || true
[74046 ms] 
[74046 ms] ls: cannot access /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache: No such file or directory
```

If I try to install the extensions manually, using the Extensions panel they are getting installed, but it is very hard to do it over and over every time something changes in the Dockerfile.

I used to have an issue with proxy, which gave similar issues even though then it did wrote specifically about timeout, but that was fixed.

How can I diagnose what is the problem?

Comment: Any Luck? I'm having similar extension issues. Sometimes they install, mostly they don't.